# How to write in C code?

Tags: c, perl

Here I have some Perl code:

```
sub clustering {
    ($brapa,$gee) = @_;
    $g=0;
    while ($g<$brapa) {
        if (($Y1XY[$g]-$Y2XY[$g])<=0) { push(@Y1new,$g+$gee);}
        else { push(@Y2new,$g+$gee);}
        $g++;
    }
    $sizeY1new = $#Y1new+1;
    $sizeY2new = $#Y2new+1;
}
```

The problem is that I have try to write it in C like this:

```
int clustering (int brapa, int gee){
    int g;
    g=0;
    while (g<brapa) {
        if ((jarakY1-jarakY2)<=0) { /*stuck at here*/ }
        else { }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I call data/results from jarakY1 and jarakY2?  Then, how do I write it perfectly in C?  Please help me.

Comment: The answer is: Learn C. There are many good books on the subject, and tutorials on the net.

Comment: what are `jarakY1` and `jarakY2`?

Comment: Your C code is not equivalent in terms of variable scopes. Use `my` in Perl code!

Comment: @Brian: The best thing is to ask someone who can answer that means in here, if I learn from books alone. I'll probably get lost. Help me if you can, please. :)

Comment: @Nick: jarakY1 and jarakY2 is distance from other calculations that I has done before this. So how can I call that result for other functions in C code?

Comment: @Benoit: I ask how to convert it in C code, no more Perl code. :)

Comment: Rather than C, write it in C++ and use standard container classes

Comment: @Mohd - per your previous questions, You don't know perl, and you don't know C ... what you're trying to do is so beyond your abilities you don't even know what questions to ask. SO is here to help people, but it's not somewhere you come to have people do things for you which in this case is the only option.

Comment: @Brian: I don't know how to write Perl code in C code, I know that function. But I don't know how to write it back in C code. For example, I don't know how to call back results from other functions in C code. Can you tell me, how to do it? Please.

Comment: @Mohd Isa: Then declare `i`, `brapa`, `gee`, `g`, etc. global if you want equivalent code!

Comment: @Benoit: How to make it global?

Comment: @mohd what books do you have to learn from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl has built in data types and functions which aren't provided in C.  It is the case for push.  You'll have to write your own stack, list or variable length array handling yourself depending on how you use the result.

Comment: So, I need know how to write my own stack, list or variable length array. Can you teach me how to write it or you can suggest some other link to I learn. Please.

Comment: @mohd I'm sure you could find someone to teach you for a fee! Otherwise you might be better with a book. Why C?

Comment: @Mohd Isa, yes I could but it is out of the scope of what I'm ready to do on a site like Stack Overflow.  I don't want to spend the time needed for once, and I don't think SO format is suitable for the task.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping me. I will do it slowly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

My first question is: why are you converting Perl code into C?

There are a great many C libraries providing something like Perl arrays, don't write your own.  One is the Gnome C Library (aka glib) which has [several Array types that you can push to](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html#g-array-append-val).

The other alternative is to write it using C++ and the Standard Template Library (aka the STL).  They have [a list type with push_front](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/push_front/).

You can use [Perl arrays from C](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#Array-Manipulation-Functions), though that isn't the simplest thing to do.

Finally, here's [a question about learning C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171126/learning-c-and-or-c-from-beginner-to-advanced) which has some good answers.